# Is it possible to use SQL in Exchange transport rules

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, sql

I'm looking into using Microsoft Exchange transport rules for adding some dynamic content to email signatures. I already know that I could pull dynamic data from Active Directory, but I haven't found anywhere any information on whether it is possible to use SQL with a transport rule.

So, my question: is it possible, via an API/SDK or just within a transport rule itself, to connect to a SQL database and pull data dynamically similar to the way you can pull dynamic data from AD attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, but not via transport rules. Hence these only allow basic HTML and these `{{name}}` attributes. You might want to look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Aa579261(v=exchg.150).aspx). It describes how to create custom transport agents. These would allow you to modify any outgoing message with the full ability of .NET and C#.